# combinatorics question.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 20 TV's, four of them are with defects. Company bought 3 TV's. What is probability that only 2 TV's are with defects.

My approach was:

C(4,2)*C(16,1)/C(20,3) = (2*3*16)/(20*19*18) = 4/285, but the answer is 8/95. Where I'am wrong?

Comment: Your approach is correct, but your calculation of $C(20,3)$ is incorrect.

Comment: Oh yeah I see it but still (2*3*16)/1140 = (2*3*4)/285 = 24/285 but still isn't right. Or I'm just very confused

Comment: $\binom{4}{2}\binom{16}{1}\binom{20}{3}^{-1}=6.16.1140^{-1}=8.95^{-1}$. Just note that $24=3\times 8$ and $285=3\times 95$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct (and that's the main thing!). What you did wrong is to be found in the calculation especially of $\binom{20}{3}$ denoted in your question as $C(20,3)$. It is not $C(20,3)=20\times19\times18$ (actually that is $P(20,3)$) but this must be divided by $3!$. You just forgot that.  If mistakes are vanished then we find a probability equal to: $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{16}{1}\binom{20}{3}^{-1}=\frac{6\times 16}{1140}=\frac{8}{95}$$